# How to update column values depending on another column's values with CASE WHEN in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable

I have a MySQL database table called `groovers`, in this table I have a `gender` column and `profileImage` column, I want to change all the values of the column `profileImage` depending on what the `gender` value is where
if `gender`='Male' then `profileImage`='imgM'
if `gender`='Female' then `profileImage`='imgF'
if 'Unspecified' then `profileImage`='default'
I have a row with a Male gender and another row with Female gender, when I execute the code, the `profileImage` doesn't change.
Here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT gender, profileImage,
    CASE
        WHEN gender ='Male'
        THEN profileImage = 'imgM'

        WHEN gender = 'Female'
        THEN profileImage = 'imgF'

        ELSE profileImage = 'default'

        END
FROM
    groovers
```

here's my table's

```
CREATE TABLE groovers
(
    user_id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username        VARCHAR(40)                                                  NOT NULL,
    firstName       VARCHAR(40)                                                  NOT NULL,
    lastName        VARCHAR(40)                                                  NOT NULL,
    gender          enum ('Male', 'Female', 'Unspecified') default 'Unspecified' NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR(255)                                                 NOT NULL,
    password        VARCHAR(32)                                                  NOT NULL,
    profileImage    VARCHAR(255)                                                 NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: please show us rhe data of your table and as i see an enum als the create table please

Comment: @nbk I edited the question, you can see te table now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update the table
use

```
UPDATE groovers
SET profileImage = CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 'imgM'
                        WHEN gender = 'female' THEN 'imgF'
                        ELSE 'default' END;
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE groovers
(
    user_id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username        VARCHAR(40)                                                  NOT NULL,
    firstName       VARCHAR(40)                                                  NOT NULL,
    lastName        VARCHAR(40)                                                  NOT NULL,
    gender          enum ('Male', 'Female', 'Unspecified') default 'Unspecified' NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR(255)                                                 NOT NULL,
    password        VARCHAR(32)                                                  NOT NULL,
    profileImage    VARCHAR(255)                                                 NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO groovers VALUES (0,'test','test','test','male','test@test.com','a',''),
(0,'test','test','test','female','test@test.com','a',''),
(0,'test','test','test','Unspecified','test@test.com','a','');

UPDATE groovers
SET profileImage = CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 'imgM'
                        WHEN gender = 'female' THEN 'imgF'
                        ELSE 'default' END;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM groovers;

| user_id | username | firstName | lastName | gender      | email         | password | profileImage |
| ------- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ----------- | ------------- | -------- | ------------ |
| 1       | test     | test      | test     | Male        | test@test.com | a        | imgM         |
| 2       | test     | test      | test     | Female      | test@test.com | a        | imgF         |
| 3       | test     | test      | test     | Unspecified | test@test.com | a        | default      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't change.  You have added a *third* column.  If you want to do this in a `select` just name the new column and remove the old one:

```
SELECT gender,
       (CASE WHEN gender ='Male' THEN 'imgM'
             WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 'imgF'
             ELSE 'default'
        END) as profileImage
FROM groovers;
```

You can change this in the table itself using an `update`.

Comment: it doesn't work, the `gender` for the first row is 'Male' and the `profileImage` is still 'default' and the same for the second row where `gender` is 'Female'. does the datatype of `gender` has anything to do with this? because its not ```VARCHAR``` it's ```ENUM('Male','Female','Unspecified')```

Comment: @WassimTahraoui . . . As I say in the answer, this provides the right value in a `SELECT`.  You need an `UPDATE` to actually change the value in the tble.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use the below query

```
update groovers set
     profileImage = (CASE WHEN gender ='Male' THEN 'imgM'
             WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 'imgF'
             ELSE 'default'
            END);
```